# Spring boot security - two distinct filters

Tags: java, spring, filtering

I am trying to configure spring security with two distinct filters. 
What i want is to have some URLs which will be processed by one filter, and some URLs which will be processed by other filter.
This is the setup i came up with :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true,prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfigurationContext {

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class ConfigurerAdapter1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        ...

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // Handlers and entry points
            http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(MyCustomAuthenticationEntryPoint);


            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/filter1-urls/*").hasRole("USER");


            http.addFilterBefore(myCustomFilter1, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

            http.csrf().disable();
            http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(myCustomAuthenticationService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public static class ConfigurerAdapter2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        ...

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // Handlers and entry points
            http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(MyCustomAuthenticationEntryPoint);


            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/filter2-urls/*").hasRole("SUPER_USER");


            http.addFilterBefore(myCustomFilter2, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

            http.csrf().disable();
            http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(myCustomAuthenticationService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }
    }
}
```

And filters look like this :

Filter1 :

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public final class MyCustomFilter1 implements Filter{

    public MyCustomFilter1() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // logic for processing filter1-urls
    }
}
```

Filter2 :

```
@Component
@Order(2)
public final class MyCustomFilter2 implements Filter{

    public MyCustomFilter2() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // logic for processing filter2-urls
    }
}
```

The problem is that both of these filters are invoked in a chain for every request. Any request i make, it first passes through one filter and then the other, rather then just through one.

How do i fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the only one `ConfigurerAdapter`. You can combine it into one configuration:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(MyCustomAuthenticationEntryPoint);
http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/filter1-urls/*").hasRole("USER")
     .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/filter2-urls/*").hasRole("SUPER_USER");
http.addFilterBefore(myCustomFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
```

Both of filters will be invoked because you set such behavior. You should left the only one filter to achieve the result you want.

```
@Component
public final class MyCustomFilter implements Filter {

    public MyCustomFilter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // logic for processing filter2-urls and filter1-urls
    }
 }
```

Anyway your filters will be invoked in a chain. If you want to split your filters you should add `if` statement in your filters to filter only needed url (you can get request url from `ServletRequest`

```
@Component
public final class MyCustomFilter2 implements Filter {

    public MyCustomFilter2() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (/*is filter2 urls*/) {
        // logic for processing filter2-urls
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hmmmm. Thanks. I'll give it a try and let you know if i managed.